# Why I cannot loop through array backwards in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

The reverseLoop function below threw VM error: invalid opcode. Why is that?

```
contract ArrayTest {
  uint[2] a;

  event ReverseLoop(uint n);
  event NormalLoop(uint n);

  constructor() public {
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
  }

  function reverseLoop() external {
    for (uint i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        emit ReverseLoop(a[i]);
    }
  }

  function normalLoop() external {
    for (uint i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        emit NormalLoop(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just realised the correct implementation should be

```
for (uint i = a.length; i > 0; i--) {
    emit ReverseLoop(a[i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `i` will underflow and it will become uint.max-1 value, this index does not exist so it reverts;
why underflow? because when `i` reaches 0, and emits the event, the next step will be to execute `i--` this will underflow the value.
If you use solidity >= 0.8.0, it will revert too because of the protection.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Saw your answer and tried it out, works fine. Still wondering why the original way you had it runs infinitely!

---

Okay, so I went through Remix and compiled your code. reverseLoop throws an invalid opcode error and when I look at the mined transaction, the transaction cost is the gas limit. When I increase the gas limit, the transaction cost goes up to the gas limit. So it must be going through an infinite loop.

Comment: The reason is that the original implementation is an infinite loop. When. `i` is `0` the loop decrements it again, but since it's an unsigned integer it undeflows and loops back to the maximum uint